# Makefile errors while executing in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have one requirement in my automation.

I need to pass values like 1, 2, 3 to MY_IMAGE in command line in Linux.

I had defines activities for all these inputs in other make file.

The code similar to below i wrote for my requirement. Issue was whenever I passes values like MY_IMAGE=1, MY_IMAGE=2, MY_IMAGE=3

it's printing only `echo ACT_DO=XYZ;`

It's not displaying the other info whenever I selected 2 or 3. Can anyone check and correct my code.

```
export MY_IMAGE
MY_IMAGE=$img_value;
if [ $img_value :="1" ]
then
echo ACT_DO=XYZ;
else 
if [ $img_value :="2 ] 
then
echo ACT_DO=ABC;
else 
if [ $img_value :=3 ] 
then
echo ACT_DO=ETC;
else
echo ""$img_value" is unsupported";
exit 1; 
fi
fi
fi
```

Comment: This is not makefile syntax. Is it a shell script?

Comment: the mentioned code is correct for the requirement ? if it is shell also fine.

Comment: This code cannot possibly work: a `"` quote is missing. The `:=` look wrong, too (why not `=`?)  Please copy and paste when you post code examples.

Comment: What shell are you using? It looks like `bash` as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a quote in the wrong place, and uses `:=` which doesn't mean anything, as far as I know. It's also implemented confusingly.

Try this:

```
export MY_IMAGE
MY_IMAGE=$img_value

case "$img_value" in
1 ) echo ACT_DO=XYZ ;;
2 ) echo ACT_DO=ABC ;;
3 ) echo ACT_DO=ETC ;;
* )
  echo "\"$img_value\" is unsupported"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

The first two lines are not required for this code, but I presume you wanted that for something else.