# Shell script showing errors while executing in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, shellexecute

SCRIPT :

```
IMAGE=$imgvalue;
if  [ $imgvalue :=1 ]
then
    echo DO=ABC;
elif [ $imgvalue :=2 ]
then
    echo DO=ETC;
elif [ $imgvalue :=3 ]
then
    echo DO=XYZ;
else
    echo "$imgvalue is unsupported";
    exit 1; 
fi
```

In the script above, `IMAGE=1`, `IMAGE=2`, `IMAGE=3` whatever may be the value I have assigned. It's showing only `DO=ABC`. Other conditions not working. Can anyone explain what's wrong with my script?

Comment: Very similar to your last [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10509775/1330481) ?

Comment: Just for my education Isn't `IMAGE=$imgvalue` backwards?

Comment: Or is it because of exporting to the new shell not the command line shell?

Answer (score 0):

If `$imgvalue` is not an empty string, your first test is a syntax error, so I am assuming it is empty in the tests you are doing.  In that case, your first test is equivalent to:

```
if [ :=1 ]
```

which is always true because `:=1` is not an empty string.  You probably meant to write:

```
if [ "$imgvalue" = 1 ]
```